# How to make footnote numbers invisible in ConTeXt?

Tags: footnotes, context, context-mkiv

I need to put some comments in the footnotes area in a document, but without any note numbers appearing. I've tried several things, including `\footnote[numbercommand={}]{This is the footnote}`, but nothing is working. I need the numbers in the text and the numbers near the footnote to both disappear.

How can I make the footnote numbers invisible in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `numbercommand` and `textcommand` keys. The command
`\gobbleoneargument` does what you might think it does, it removes the
argument which makes the text vanish.

```
\setupnotation
  [footnote]
  [numbercommand=\gobbleoneargument]

\setupnote
  [footnote]
  [textcommand=\gobbleoneargument]

\starttext
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  \startfootnote
    \input knuth
  \stopfootnote
\stoptext
```